# Add class on the basis of rel value of anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have a li thatis as follows:-

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($bannerCollection as $banner): $i++; ?>
 <li><a href="#" class="pagination" rel="tab<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This php code generate following Html code:-

```
<div id="pettabs" class="indentmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="pagination" rel="tab1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="pagination" rel="tab2">2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Now I wanted to add one more class named "selected" to anchor on the basis of rel value.
For that I use

```
jQuery('a.pagination').removeClass('selected').filter('a.pagination[rel=idvalue]').addClass('selected');
```

But it doesn't work. Please Help me.

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rel` attribute will start with "tag", so you filter would need to be more like

```
var idvalue = 'tag2';
.filter('a.pagination[rel='+idvalue+']')
```

Currently you are sending in a string `[rel=idvalue]`

Edit: It would be better to use a class rather than rel, so you generated code would be

```
<li><a href="#" class="pagination tag1">1</a></li>
```

Then you could select it with

```
.filter('a.pagination.tag'+id)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i cant do it as idvalue is value of if that I am getting like this var idvalue=jQuery('.show').attr('id')

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing double quotes around your idvalue.

Should be:

```
.filter('a.pagination[rel="idvalue"]')
```